# Using Time Stamps to Get New Logs Dynamically

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, groovy, timestamp

I am trying to create a log service, which gets the logs from the POSTGRESQL database using time stamps and writes it to a txt file.

I am using **time stamps to get the data from the first log created to the last log created**, let's say logs (1-103) and **this 1-103** **is not fixed**, which means that number of logs depends on how much logs are in the server at that specific time. However, since this will be running continuously, **I like to find a way to start from the time when 104 was made until the last log created let's say 206** **and then logs 207-304 so on...**

Is there a way to store the last time stamp so it can be used the next time the script runs, and it will be used as the new starting time stamp

Question:

How will I change this line:
**"SELECT * from audit_log where created < (CURRENT_DATE) order by id ASC"**

```
 try {

         BufferedWriter outputFile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/test/project/testProd1.txt", true))
         def logs = new Logs()
         String query = "SELECT * from audit_log where created < (CURRENT_DATE) order by id ASC"
         PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(query)

         ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery()

         while(result.next()){
             String id1 = result.getString("id")
             logs.id = id1

             String created1 = result.getString("created")
             logs.created = created1

             String summary1 = result.getString("summary")
             logs.summary = summary1

             String category1 = result.getString("category")
             logs.category = category1

             String searchField1 = result.getString("search_field")
             logs.searchField = searchField1

             outputFile.write("[GRP] "+logs.toString())
             outputFile.newLine()

            }            
            outputFile.close()

            return ("[GRP] "+logs.toString())
        }
```

Comment: You can store it to a file or in db and then fetch & update before running your query.

Comment: @SandeepPoonia What do you mean by fetch and update before running the query? Is there a way I can change it on my code, because that's the only thing i can change

Comment: Before executing the query, get the time info from file/db when you last accessed the log table. This would be the start time for your logs. Update current time in file/db before executing the query, so that you can use it in next cycle.

Comment: @SandeepPoonia do you have any sample code? Where I can study off?